# Maximum possible order of pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is the maximum possible order of pde with n independent variables equal to n?
I think it can be more than n because we can take partial derivatives any number of times. Just asking cause someone told me.

Comment: No, there is no such restriction. The order of the pde means the highest derivative which appears in it, and this has nothing to do with the number of variables.

Comment: Thankyou @Snaw .